# Receiving continuous responses from service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am using Angular 2 and I am trying to display user-nickname from the User ID. When I call the function getUserName(userId) from dashboard.component.html, which then calls the auth0 service to fetch the user profile. As a result I am receiving continuous responses, and am unable to display the user-nickname. Please find the code below:

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Auth0Service } from '../../services/auth0/auth0.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent  {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _auth0Service: Auth0Service){

}

getUserName(userId:string){
    let userName:string;
    this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
        .subscribe(user=>{
            userName=user.nickname;
        });
    }
    return userName;
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<h1>User Dashboard</h1>
{{getUserName(authService.userProfile.user_id)}}
```

auth0.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Auth0Service {

constructor(private _http:Http, private _authHttp: AuthHttp) {
}

getUser(userId: string){
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer token');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this._http.get('https://url.auth0.com/api/v2/users/'+userId, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, Routing, HttpModule, ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ AUTH_PROVIDERS, AuthService, Auth0Service, AuthGuard, ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please note I want to call the function from the HTML, as I want to use this function in my comments section as well, where the userIds will be different!!! I have to pass each Id to the function and get the result. Awaiting your earliest help!!!

Thanks
Abbas

Comment: `constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _auth0Service: Auth0Service)` authService is private here and you are using it as `{{getUserName(authService.userProfile.user_id)}}`

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTP calls are asynchronous, you are returning `userName` before getting the response. This should do it :

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

userName : string;

export class DashboardComponent  {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _auth0Service: Auth0Service){

}

getUserName(userId:string){
    this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
        .subscribe(user=>{
            return user.nickname;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to call it from html!!! For example, I need the username from ID for all the persons who commented in comments section?

Comment: You don't need to call it from the HTML to do so. You could always bind the data loading to an event.

Comment: Any example please...? '<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArray; let i = index">
    {{getUserName(comment.comment_by)}}: {{comment.comment_text}}
   </li>'

Comment: Now you can still not use ngOnInit() it should be fine. As long as you don't return the value before the response arrived.

Comment: `<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArray; let i = index"> {{userName}}: {{comment.comment_text}}`

Comment: userId's in comments can be different. I should pass each Id to the function to get the name of the particular Id. Do you get my point?

Comment: If I do `.subscribe(user=>{console.log(user);});` I am receiving continuous responses... never ending!

Comment: anything I can do, @YounesM ??

Comment: Continuous responses ? Containing what ?

Comment: If I console.log user, the console displays user object again and again repeatedly and never stops until I close the browser!

Comment: Is it the same user object ?

Comment: That's weird. What if you `this._auth0Service.getUser(userId).unsubscribe()` after receiving the data ?

Comment: After doing some digging up try : `{{getUserName(authService.userProfile.user_id) | async}}`

Answer (score 0):

Please call the method getUserName(userId) from the component. You can call the function on the onInit of the component.
For eg:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
    import { Auth0Service } from '../../services/auth0/auth0.service';

    @Component({
       moduleId: module.id,
       selector: 'dashboard',
       templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
   })

    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

      constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _auth0Service: Auth0Service){}

      userName:string="";

      ngOnInit(){
        this.getUserName(this.authService.userProfile.user_id);
       }

      getUserName(userId:string){
        let userName:string;
        this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
            .subscribe(user=>{
                this.userName=user.nickname;
            });
        }
       }    
    }
```

and in your html

```
<h1>User Dashboard</h1>
 {{userName}}
```

Comment: I know, but I want to call it from HTML :-). Because I have to use the function in my comments section, where I am getting the user ids and want to display the username! I hope you get my point

Comment: then it will be better by getting username as response along with the userid. why you call an extra method for it? @MuhammadAbbas

Comment: Because I am storing User Ids in the database!!! User Profiles are on another database of Auth0!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function on the onInit of the component. For Example see the below code

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
let Userid:string;

     constructor(private authService: AuthService){
       Userid=this.authService.userProfile.user_id;
         }

      ngOnInit(){
        this.getUserName(this.Userid);
       }

      getUserName(userId:string){
        let userName:string;
        this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
            .subscribe(user=>{
                userName=user.nickname;
            });
        }
        return userName;
       }    
    }
```

Comment: I want to call it from html!!! Because for example, I need the username from ID for all the persons who commented in comments section? `<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArray; let i = index"> {{getUserName(comment.comment_by)}}: {{comment.comment_text}} </li>`

Comment: `<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArray | async; trackBy:trackByContactId"> {{getUserName(comment.comment_by)}}: {{comment.comment_text}} </li>
    ` 
      in your component `trackByContactId(index, comment) {
        return comment.comment_by;
      }`

Comment: This shows an error. caused by: Invalid argument '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'